# Iterate NavigableSet without having entrySet() available

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, treemap, aem

I have a TreeMap that I reverse sorted by key, and am trying to loop through to output values, but NavigableSet doesn't have `entrySet()` as a method, which is all the examples I am finding.

My java is very rookie, so I am limited with my knowledge right now to modify code I see in examples.

```
<%@page
import="java.util.Iterator,
        java.util.Map,
        java.util.TreeMap,
        java.util.NavigableSet,
        com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter"
%>

    TreeMap<String, String> news = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    String listroot = properties.get("listRoot", currentPage.getPath());
    Page rootPage = pageManager.getPage(listroot);
    if (rootPage != null) {
        Iterator<Page> children = rootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter(request));
        while (children.hasNext()) {
            Page child = children.next();

            String title = child.getTitle(); //value
            String url = child.getPath(); //value
            String dcreated = child.getProperties().get("jcr:created",""); //key

            news.put( dcreated, title + "::" + url );
        }
        NavigableSet nset = news.descendingKeySet(); //Reverse order the entries
        for( String value : nset.values()  ) { //I know this is incorrect.
            out.println( value + "<br>");
        }
    }
%>
```

I am sure there is a much more efficient way of doing this, but for now this is what I could come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
news.descendingMap().entrySet();
```

Comment: I did `for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : news.descendingMap().entrySet() )`, and output with `entry.getValue()`, which works well. I assume this is how your suggestion was to be implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Use an iterator to loop through the set. Looking at the [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) and [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) apis I found a method that gives the descending iterator so creating a new set in reverse order is not necessary.

Edit: The above was with the wrong assumption that `news` was of Type `TreeSet` not the correct `TreeMap`. Code was changed to the correct type to be correct code.

```
Iterator newsItr = news.descendingKeySet().iterator();
while(newsIter.hasNext()){
    out.println( news.get(newsItr.next()) + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: `descendingIterator()` is type NavigableSet, so do I convert the TreeMap before using the Iterator declaration? And is `newsItr` only an value that loops through the set, or does it actually contain all the values?

Comment: That works, except you have distinctly written *newsItr* and *newsIter*. I adjusted it in my code.

Comment: I mixed NavigableSet and TreeMap for your news var. I've fixed my code example. My understanding is that the for each construct  abstracts out the very common use of iterators to just loop through a collection.

Comment: how is this example any different than the original code example?

Comment: @jtahlborn This example is the un-abstracted version of the for each construct. It is the most common use of iterators, but is not the only use of iterators. More complicated actions during looping can be achieved with direct access to the iterator that can not be done in a for each loop

Comment: sure, but the question wasn't about un-abstracting the iterator, it was about getting an entry set instead of a key set.  (also, don't understand your statement about "creating a new set is not necessary" since none of the examples are creating a new set).

Comment: My initial response was a more concise example, but it was wrong because it was with the wrong type for `news`. I updated the code to use the correct type, but did not change the description.